# Web links in Adobe reader opens Firefox even if another browser (Opera, Chrome) is default

Tags: adobe-reader, default-browser

I think that title describes my problem clearly. Clicking a hyperlink in Adobe Reader opens Firefox, but I have another browser set as default. Does anyone know a solution?

regards
Jan

Answer (score 1):

1. Install **Ubuntu Tweak** as explained here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak
2. Start **Ubuntu Tweak**, go to **Admins** and then **File Type Manager**
3. Replace all references to Firefox with your Default Browser